# when I built a webApp maven project by IDEA,IDEA shows me an error,why? when i built my project in cmd ,it can success?

Tags: java, maven

when I built a webApp maven project in IDEA,IDEA shows me an error,why? when i built my project in cmd ,it can success?Please give me some help.Thanks very much!!

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Could you add your pom.xml file with the relevant information?

Comment: I can't because i just want to built an empty project .Have you used the IntelliJ IDEA? And here are my steps:1. new moudle   2.select  `maven`  3.  select`create from archetype ` 4. choose `maven-archetype-webapp`  .In usual IDEA will built a complete project for me successfully,but today it showed me an error.

Comment: Yes, if the project is based on Maven, it must have a pom.xml file

Comment: I know...but  when  i built the project in command `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.lhp.pyg -DartifactId=pyg-cart-service -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp`,it will be success.Now I want built it by IDEA ,I don't have to write the command .As for pom.xml, I think it is generated by maven.After maven built it success,I can do some configuration in it.  Thanks !!!

Comment: ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>pyg-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.lhp.pyg</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>adaad</artifactId>


</project>```

Comment: Please, go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing, and on the right side, tell me if you have the **Import Maven projects automatically** checked

Comment: OK ,it is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created your project doing this: *File -> New -> Project -> Maven -> (Create from Archetype) -> maven-archetype-webapp -> Next*

After that, you filled your *GroupId* and *ArtifactId*

The next screen is the one that you need to modify: edit the **archetypeVersion** and set it to 1.4 (you could select one version from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp))

[image: Maven archetype]

Then continue the process until the end, and you should be able to run your project from IntelliJ

Comment: Thanks  very much~~~It's usueful!